# how to load a program when using a simple proxy code?

Tags: c, proxy, antivirus

I'm using this simple proxy code, written in C and created by godlytalias, and i want to load another program I built in C which check for a virus signature when a file is downloaded.
how can i manipulate the proxy code so whenever i'm downloading something, my program is running.

this is the proxy code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<errno.h>

void error(char* msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(0);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
pid_t pid;
struct sockaddr_in addr_in,cli_addr,serv_addr;
struct hostent* host;
int sockfd,newsockfd;

if(argc<2)
error("./proxy <port_no>");

printf("\n*****WELCOME TO PROXY SERVER*****\n");
printf("\nCopyright (c) 2014  GODLY T.ALIAS\n\n");

bzero((char*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
bzero((char*)&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;


sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sockfd<0)
error("Problem in initializing socket");

if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
error("Error on binding");


listen(sockfd,50);
int clilen=sizeof(cli_addr);



accepting:

newsockfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,&clilen);

if(newsockfd<0)
error("Problem in accepting connection");

pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{
struct sockaddr_in host_addr;
int flag=0,newsockfd1,n,port=0,i,sockfd1;
char buffer[510],t1[300],t2[300],t3[10];
char* temp=NULL;
bzero((char*)buffer,500);
recv(newsockfd,buffer,500,0);

sscanf(buffer,"%s %s %s",t1,t2,t3);


if(((strncmp(t1,"GET",3)==0))&&((strncmp(t3,"HTTP/1.1",8)==0)| (strncmp(t3,"HTTP/1.0",8)==0))&&(strncmp(t2,"http://",7)==0))
{
strcpy(t1,t2);

flag=0;

for(i=7;i<strlen(t2);i++)
{
if(t2[i]==':')
{
flag=1;
break;
}
}

temp=strtok(t2,"//");
if(flag==0)
{
port=80;
temp=strtok(NULL,"/");
}
else
{
temp=strtok(NULL,":");
}

sprintf(t2,"%s",temp);
printf("host = %s",t2);
host=gethostbyname(t2);

if(flag==1)
{
temp=strtok(NULL,"/");
port=atoi(temp);
}


strcat(t1,"^]");
temp=strtok(t1,"//");
temp=strtok(NULL,"/");
if(temp!=NULL)
temp=strtok(NULL,"^]");
printf("\npath = %s\nPort = %d\n",temp,port);


bzero((char*)&host_addr,sizeof(host_addr));
host_addr.sin_port=htons(port);
host_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
bcopy((char*)host->h_addr,(char*)&host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,host-  >h_length);

sockfd1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
newsockfd1=connect(sockfd1,(struct sockaddr*)&host_addr,sizeof(struct  sockaddr));
sprintf(buffer,"\nConnected to %s  IP -   %s\n",t2,inet_ntoa(host_addr.sin_addr));
if(newsockfd1<0)
error("Error in connecting to remote server");

printf("\n%s\n",buffer);
//send(newsockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
bzero((char*)buffer,sizeof(buffer));
if(temp!=NULL)
sprintf(buffer,"GET /%s %s\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection:    close\r\n\r\n",temp,t3,t2);
else
sprintf(buffer,"GET / %s\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection:   close\r\n\r\n",t3,t2);


n=send(sockfd1,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
printf("\n%s\n",buffer);
if(n<0)
error("Error writing to socket");
else{
do
{
bzero((char*)buffer,500);
n=recv(sockfd1,buffer,500,0);
if(!(n<=0))
send(newsockfd,buffer,n,0);
}while(n>0);
}
}
else
{
send(newsockfd,"400 : BAD REQUEST\nONLY HTTP REQUESTS ALLOWED",18,0);
}
close(sockfd1);
close(newsockfd);
close(sockfd);
_exit(0);
}
else
{
close(newsockfd);
goto accepting;
}
return 0;
}
```

first time asking here, hope it's fine.
thanks for ur help!

Comment: What did you try? Also format your code.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea where to start from. I can't figure out where is the connection between proxy and file's downloading.